# Chrome Everything too big on Ubuntu Gnome 15.04

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu-15.04

As you can see on the attached screenshot, I randomly opened Chrome to this. I have Chrome version 43.0.2357.125 (64-bit) and I've reinstalled it many times; with or without signing into my profile. It only does this on Chrome.

Thanks

Raza

[image: Left side]

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling probably isn't removing your preferences. Try going to `~/.config` and deleting the Chrome related directory. Also, see [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/251410/reset-all-google-chrome-settings-on-ubuntu).

Comment: is this the same for other apps? or just chrome. also, whats your graphics card installed

Comment: Not a programming question. Ask on [su]

Comment: @aidan, yes, I just removed that too, and tried again. Still. no avail.

Comment: @bernlim, yes, this is only on Chrome. Nothing else.